# dart nnbd Future.ontimeout fails with null value

Tags: dart, future

I'm migrating unit test to nnbd.

```dart
#! /usr/bin/env dcli

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dcli/dcli.dart';

import 'package:args/args.dart';

/// dcli script generated by:
/// dcli create future.dart
///
/// See
/// https://pub.dev/packages/dcli#-installing-tab-
///
/// For details on installing dcli.
///

Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  var testClient = TestClient();

  final Future<TestResponse?> outageResponseFuture =
      testClient.request('/outage').get();

  // Introduce a delay to ensure that the /outage request gets there before /success
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  final successResponse = await testClient.request('/success').get();

  await outageResponseFuture.timeout(const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      onTimeout: () => Future.value(null));
}

class TestClient {
  TestRequest request(String s) => TestRequest();
}

class TestRequest {
  Future<TestResponse> get() => Future.value(TestResponse());
}

class TestResponse {}
```

```yaml
name: stackoverflow
version: 0.0.1
description: A script generated by dcli.
environment: 
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'
dependencies: 
  args: ^2.0.0
  dcli: ^0.51.0
  path: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies: 
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
```

```yaml
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

# For lint rules and documentation, see http://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints.
# Uncomment to specify additional rules.
linter:
  
  rules:
    lines_longer_than_80_chars: false
    camel_case_types: true
    always_declare_return_types: true
  

analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
```

The problem is with the call to timeout. When the code runs I get:

```dart
type '() => Future<TestResponse?>' is not a subtype of type '(() => FutureOr<TestResponse>)?' of 'onTimeout'
```

The problem is with the onTimeout returning null. I've tried declaring `response` with every possible combination of ? but it makes no difference.

Any clues?

Comment: I don't have any trouble with your code (after stubbing out or removing references to things you didn't include).  Could you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: @jamesdin I've updated the code to a self contained example that shows the problem. You can run the code in vscode or by running 'dart future.dart' from the cli.

Comment: The problem seems to go away if you fix `TestRequest.get` and `outageResponseFuture` to have consistent types (i.e., both `Future<TestResponse?>`). (Or better, remove the explicit type from `outageResponseFuture` and let it be inferred.)